# split() on one character OR another

Tags: python-3.x, split

Python 3.6.0

I have a program that parses output from Cisco switches and routers.

I get to a point in the program where I am returning output from the 'sh ip int brief'
command.

I place it in a list so I can split on the '>' character and extract the hostname.

It works perfectly.  Pertinent code snippet:

```
    ssh_channel.send("show ip int brief | exc down" + "\n")
    # ssh_channel.send("show ip int brief" + "\n")
    time.sleep(0.6)
    outp = ssh_channel.recv(5000)
    mystring = outp.decode("utf-8")
    ipbrieflist = mystring.splitlines()
    hostnamelist = ipbrieflist[1].split('>')
    hostname = hostnamelist[0]
```

If the router is in 'enable' mode the command prompt has a '#' character after the hostname.

If I change my program to split on the '#' character:

```
    hostnamelist = ipbrieflist[1].split('#')
```

it still works perfectly.

I need for the program to handle if the output has the '>' character OR the '#' character in 'ipbrieflist'.

I have found several valid references for how to handle this.  Ex:

```
import re
text = 'The quick brown\nfox jumps*over the lazy dog.'
print(re.split('; |, |\*|\n',text))
```

The above code works perfectly.

However, when I modify my code as follows:

```
    hostnamelist = ipbrieflist[1].split('> |#')
```

It does not work.  By 'does not work' I mean it does not split on either character.  No splitting at all.

The following debug is from PyCharm:

ipbrieflist = mystring.splitlines() ipbrieflist={list}: ['terminal length 0', 'rtr-1841>show ip int brief | exc down', 'Interface']                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol', 'FastEthernet0/1            192.168.1.204   YES NVRAM  up                    up      ', 'Loopback0                  172.17.0.1      YES NVRAM  up                    up      ', '', 'rtr-1841>']
hostnamelist = ipbrieflist[1].split('> |#') hostnamelist={list}: ['rtr-1841>show ip int brief | exc down']
hostname = {str}'rtr-1841>show ip int brief | exc down'

As you can see the hostname variable still contains the 'show ip int brief | exc down' appended to it.

I get the same exact behavior if the hostname is followed by the '#' character.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: uh, `re.split` != `str.split`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
ipbrieflist[1].split('> |#')
```

You want this:

```
re.split('>|#', ipbrieflist[1])
```

Comment: This worked -- BUT -- PyCharm gave me a warning about using a different syntax which it said was much faster:          hostnamelist = re.split('[>#]', ipbrieflist[1])   This also works.

Comment: @MarkS: yes `[]` is better, I just didn't want to confuse the issue.